# .On event with live class and Keydown

Tags: jquery

I have an input the with a live class "btnForget", I tried this code

```
 $("document").on('keydown', '.btnForget', function() {
         alert("keydown...");
});
```

But it doesn't work if the class is not there from the beginning.

Comment: I just can't see why you talk about a "live" class here... BUT if you talk about the `.live()` METHOD, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473686/w3c-schools-example-not-working

Comment: Second reading... Just saw that: «is not there from the beginning». I suppose you talk about `.btnForget`, which is a selector in this function. What do you mean by «not there» ?

Comment: `$(document)` without quotes

Comment: @epascarello: Ok... I see why downvote on my answer. lol! Still, The event `keydown` on a button looks strange.

Comment: I didn't want to use "live" because is already deprecated, on is the replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use quotes with document

```js
<!-- works  -->
$(document).on('keydown', '.btnForget', function() {
         alert("without");
});


<!-- does not work  -->
$("document").on('keydown', '.btnForget', function() {
         alert("with");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btnForget">Click</button>
```